# Filter graphql query result

Tags: graphql

I'm new to GraphQL. I have a data structure that looks something like this:

```
{
 "employee_id": "123"
 "employee_name":"John",
 "location": {
  "city": "Delhi",
  "country": "India"
 }
}
```

I need to get all the employees whose country is India (i.e. location.country). Queries like 
Employees(employee_id:"123")
doesn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for filtering by argument:

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments

You're probably looking for

```
{
  Employees(location: { city: "Delhi"}}) {
     ...
  }
}
```

You can also turn the query around like this:

```
{
  Location(city: "Delhi") {
     Employees
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but I think the above query gets me all Employees, but shows the location only in cases where the city is "Delhi".

Here's what I tried at http://graphql.nodaljs.com/
threads {
  id,
  user (id:1){
    id,
    username
  }
}

Comment: Right, sorry, please check now.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. It says "syntax error".The query I tried is - threads (user:{id:1}) { 
id, 
user{
 id, username 
} 
}
Thank you.

Comment: You said you needed *all* employees for a certain city, use the second example above. Turn the query around and filter by location, then fetch all linked employees.